# Using firefox and Chrome Driver in selenium 2.24.0

Tags: firefox, selenium

I'm using Selenium to buid a project about automation testing but I have some problem with these lines of code :

```
String exePath = "Browser\\firefox5.0.1\\firefox.exe";
var firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
m_browser = new FirefoxDriver(new FirefoxBinary(exePath), firefoxProfile);

m_browser.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

I can't set firefox url with these codes. But if I use InternetExplorer instead, I can set IE url. I don't know where the problem is

Plz help me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the chrome driver , you will have to set a property as follows -

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chrome driver path");
```

You can download the chromedriver.exe for your OS from the following location - http://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/downloads/list

To set up the firefox driver, the Firefox binary is assumed to be in the default location for your particular operating system such as for windows - `%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe` (reference - http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver)

If firefox is in it's default location you don't have to specify the firefox binary path. But if want to do that, check out this link - [FirefoxBinary(java.io.File pathToFirefoxBinary)](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxBinary.html#FirefoxBinary%28java.io.File%29) to make sure your constructors are correct.

Comment: I can open Firefox 5.0 or whatever version I've downloaded. But I can't set its URL on adressbar by  driver.Navigate().GoToUrl() method. I don't know what's wrong

Comment: I also try driver.url = myurlstring but no effect. With that method, I can set IE's url

Comment: make sure you are using the selenium standalone jar file.

Comment: Can you tell me where I can get selenium jar file? I've never used selenium before.Thanks

Comment: I'm using Selenium C# Webdriver. When I use IE or Chrome, I download IE driver server and Chrome driver server from Selenium page. When I use Firefox, there's no need to download anything. I can open IE, Firefox and Chrome browser by selenium. But I can just set browser url for IE browser => this is the problem I meet
P/s: sorry for my poor english if you don't understand what I say.Thanks